# Unable to access JSON response from AJAX API call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, factual

I am unable to access and append the response from a AJAX call to the factual API.

I am receiving undefined errors however I try and structure the code accessing and iterating over the response.

I have managed to successfully log the data to console, now just need to add to the HTML on a page.

Below is the current code and API response structure, what I do not understand is when to use `data` and what exactly this relates to? Is this a keyword for any data received from a request or specific to certain API structures.

CODE:

```
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log('dom ready');
    $("#search").on("click", runTing);

    function runTing () {
      var url = "http://api.v3.factual.com/t/places?q=Aldi,London&filters={%22country%22:%22GB%22}&KEY=111111111111111111111111";

      $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function (data) {
         var $latitude = $("<p>").text(response.data[0].address);
         $('#info').append("$latitude");
       }
     });

    };        
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="info"></div>
</body>
```

JSON Response:

```
{  
   "version":3,
   "status":"ok",
   "response":{  
      "data":[  
         {  
            "address":"632-640 Kingsbury Rd",
            "admin_region":"England",
            "category_ids":[  
               171
            ],
            "category_labels":[  
               [  
                  "Retail",
                  "Supermarkets and Groceries"
               ]
            ],
            "country":"gb",
            "factual_id":"75fda75e-41a7-4645-b47a-9af5364fead1",
            "hours":{  
               "monday":[  
                  [  
                     "8:00",
                     "21:00"
                  ]
               ],
               "tuesday":[  
                  [  
                     "8:00",
                     "21:00"
                  ]
               ],
               "wednesday":[  
                  [  
                     "8:00",
                     "21:00"
                  ]
               ],
               "thursday":[  
                  [  
                     "8:00",
                     "21:00"
                  ]
               ],
               "friday":[  
                  [  
                     "8:00",
                     "21:00"
                  ]
               ],
               "saturday":[  
                  [  
                     "8:00",
                     "21:00"
                  ]
               ],
               "sunday":[  
                  [  
                     "10:00",
                     "16:00"
                  ]
               ]
            },
            "hours_display":"Mon-Sat 8:00 AM-9:00 PM; Sun 10:00 AM-4:00 PM",
            "latitude":51.584985,
            "locality":"London",
            "longitude":-0.279941,
            "name":"Aldi",
            "neighborhood":[  
               "Kingsbury",
               "Queensbury"
            ],
            "post_town":"London",
            "postcode":"NW9 9HN",
            "region":"Greater London",
            "tel":"0844 406 8800",
            "website":"http://www.aldi.co.uk/"
         },
         {  
            "address":"1-4 London Rd",
            "admin_region":"England",
            "category_ids":[  
               171
            ],
            "category_labels":[  
               [  
                  "Retail",
                  "Supermarkets and Groceries"
               ]
            ],
            "country":"gb",
            "factual_id":"7edfabf8-3f28-4ee4-9322-6a296ed09a59",
            "hours":{  
               "monday":[  
                  [  
                     "8:00",
                     "20:00"
                  ]
               ],
               "tuesday":[  
                  [  
                     "8:00",
                     "20:00"
                  ]
               ],
               "wednesday":[  
                  [  
                     "8:00",
                     "20:00"
                  ]
               ],
               "thursday":[  
                  [  
                     "8:00",
                     "20:00"
                  ]
               ],
               "friday":[  
                  [  
                     "8:00",
                     "20:00"
                  ]
               ],
               "saturday":[  
                  [  
                     "8:00",
                     "20:00"
                  ]
               ],
               "sunday":[  
                  [  
                     "10:00",
                     "16:00"
                  ]
               ]
            },
            "hours_display":"Mon-Sat 8:00 AM-8:00 PM; Sun 10:00 AM-4:00 PM",
            "latitude":50.829975,
            "locality":"Brighton",
            "longitude":-0.136322,
            "name":"Aldi",
            "neighborhood":[  
               "North Laines"
            ],
            "post_town":"Brighton",
            "postcode":"BN1 4JA",
            "region":"East Sussex",
            "tel":"0844 406 8800",
            "website":"http://www.aldi.co.uk/"
         },
```

Comment: Where do you define the variable `response`?

Comment: `data` is the payload returned by the ajax request. You can access `data` by accessing its properties like a normal JS object.

Comment: @analytalica `dataType: "JSON"` tell jQuery to parse it automatically.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. I'm not all that familiar with jQuery.

Comment: remove quotes around variable in append...should be `$('#info').append($latitude);`

Comment: Thanks all, very usefu!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
response.data[0].address
```

supposed to be

```
data.response.data[0].address
```

The object that is returned from the BE, is currently in `data` (parameter for the callback).

So there is one more nested layer before you try accessing the response property.

Also as @chaarlietfl pointed out

```
$('#info').append("$latitude");
                  ^         ^
                  ---------------> Need to get rid of quotes
```

Comment: Wow, I have been playing with this for 3 hours, thank you so much. So `data` is always the way to initially access the object? Then it depends the structure correct?

Comment: It is `data` in this case as the callback was `success: function (data) {` . It could have been `response` if it was `success: function (response) {` . Depends upon the parameter variable that you expect it to be named to.

Comment: So I can name the response object by what I place in `function (HERE)`? Thanks again!